# Understanding git tagging, rebasing and bare repos

Tags: git, branch, tagging, git-merge, git-bare

In git:

1. Do you tag branches or repos?
2. When you tag a branch/repo, are you only tagging the changes that are fully committed, or do you also tag changes that have been added/staged?
3. Under what circumstances would ever need to rebase a branch? Doesn't merge give you everything you need?
4. What is a "bare" repository? How is it opposed to a "non-bare" repo?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: srsly, have you tried googling any of those questions? or searching here on SO? The Pro Git book http://git-scm.com/book might also help you out. Edit: This also goes for your other questions youve posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To (briefly) answer your questions...

1. You tag *commits*, see here: [Git - Tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging)
2. See above
3. `merge` vs `rebase` is well discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge)
4. A *bare* repository in Git just contains the versioning info that's stored in the `.git` directory within a normal repo. Try it yourself `git init --bare bare; ls -la bare`

As other has suggested, **read up on Git**:

I recommend [Git SCM](http://git-scm.com/) and especially the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book) for  getting started.